# Get byte[] response from getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive() in Spring-WS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-ws

In target WebService in response is only `xs:base64binary` and JAXB does not generate a response type. 
In my invoke:

```
public Object signMessage(SigningRequestType request) {
        JAXBElement<SigningRequestType> jAXBElement = new ObjectFactory().createSigningRequestType(request);
        return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(jAXBElement,
                new SoapActionCallback(SIGN_METHOD_ACTION));
}
```

returns an `Object` and I can't simply cast to `byte[]` or serialize it.
How can I extract a byteArray result from the response?

**UDP:** Add a little more information.

`ObjectFactory()` method:

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.roskazna.ru/eb/sign/types/sgv", name = "SigningResponseType")
    public JAXBElement<byte[]> createSigningResponseType(byte[] value) {
        return new JAXBElement<byte[]>(_SigningResponseType_QNAME, byte[].class, null, ((byte[]) value));
    }
```

XSD:

```
<xs:element name="SigningResponseType" type="cst:notEmptyB64Binary"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helped my colleague Senior.

In this case `marshalSendAndReceive()` returns `JAXBElement` in fact. So:

```
public byte[] signMessage(SigningRequestType request) throws IOException {
        JAXBElement<SigningRequestType> jAXBElement 
            = new ObjectFactory().createSigningRequestType(request);

        final Object o = getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(jAXBElement,
                new SoapActionCallback("http://www.roskazna.ru/eb/sign/types/sgv/Sign"));

        return (byte[]) ((JAXBElement) o).getValue();
    }
```